# Amazon S3 API no bucket error

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3

The following is sample code from Amazon S3 API Documentation.

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'my-bucket' . strtolower($s3->key);
 
$response = $s3->create_object($bucket, 'prefix with spaces with spaces.txt', array(
    'body' => 'This is my body text.'
));
 
// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

This works on live site
but on the localhost the latter gives an error saying no bucket found

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
   $bucket = 'my-bucket';
 
  $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, 'prefix with spaces with spaces.txt', array(
    'body' => 'This is my body text.'
));
```

// Success?

but removing the  `. strtolower($s3->key);`  works

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 is case sensitive. So for Bucket as well as Object if you changes the Name to Upper or Lower Case, It will give you different result.

Means if Bucket Name has some Capital Laters and your code make changed the it name to lower case then It will returns you Bucket Does No Exist like message.

So make sure that what actually bucket as well as object name exist at Amazon S3.

Comment: Did you apply both code for same Bucket or for live server you did use the bucket which is already in lower case ?

Comment: Same bucket name on both the servers. Why we should append the key with the bucket name?

Comment: I do not have knowledge of the language (php ) you are working on. BUT 
Yes, you do not need to append key with bucket name. You are already passing key in create object method.